# full list of albums using spotify api

Tags: spotify

Has anyone pulled a full list of albums using `Spotify's API`?

I am doing analysis of `band names` and I need to get the following information:

> Band Name,Year Founded (will use the first album release date to derive this), Genre

I was planning to use `python curl`, but I can only figure out how to pull information for one `artist`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have already, please have a look at [Spotify's Developer site](https://developer.spotify.com), and more specifically [the endpoint reference](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/). There's an API endpoint to [retrieve metadata about multiple at once](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-artists/).

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists?ids={id1},{id2},..
```

If you're coding in Python, I'd recommend having a look at [Spotipy](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy), an open source Python client with language bindings for the Spotify Web API. It might save you some time, but it's not required in any way of course.

As a note of caution, since Spotify doesn't have all albums by all artists, the way you're calculating the band's founding year will sometimes be incorrect.